# GWT menubar hide when mouse out

Tags: java, gwt, menubar

We have recently attached a GWT MenuBar to a part of our application for, well, menu purposes.

I would also like to have the sub menu automatically hide when the user's mouse leaves the sub menu. Ideally with some sort of delay to prevent it vanishing too abruptly, but I'd settle for just the hiding.

So what would be the best approach to autohiding a GWT submenu?

Thanks,
Uday

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would most likely be using a pure CSS3 dropdown. An example can be found [here](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/). This was the solution we ended up going with in the end. Unfortunately, the GWT MenuBar has several limitations which have yet to be adequately resolved.